# How to Apply css to all the text boxes in the form using form id

Tags: html, css, forms

I am using jquery form validation and I need to apply color code for all the textboxes in the form without specifying each textbox id in the Css. Instead How to apply css for all the text box in the form using the form id. Please let me know is there any solutions.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
#formID input[type="text"]{
    Put your css here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in css, you can do this:

```
form input {
// Your formatting comes here..
}
```

or if you want this to apply for a specific form having an id="myForm":

```
#myForm input {
// formatting comes here for example: color:red;
}
```

The background knowledge for this is CSS Selectors.

Answer (score 1):

If by textboxes you mean `<input type="text">` and `<textarea>` elements, you can simply style them using the following:

```
#formid input[type=text],
#formid textarea {
  /* CSS rules */
}
```

> Note that `<input>` elements with types other than `text` exist. Read more about those [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes).

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```css
#frm1>input[type="text"]{
    border:1px solid red;
    width:100px;
    margin:1%;
  }
```

```html
<form id="frm1">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) function of the jQuery api to set the css properties of the form elements.

eg : [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6mjy3edu/)

```
$('#FormID').children().css("property", "value");
```